# Kannel Monthly Report for Sent SMS

Tags: kannel

I have kannel installed in Ubuntu.
Is there any way i can get report for number of sms sent via kannel? (preferably successful sent sms, because sometimes it shows GENERIC error in some sms, so i need to see report how much sms was sent on last or current month?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SQLBOX** in between **BEARERBOX** and **SMSBOX**, then all sms (MO,MT,DLR)will be logged in database with *timestamp*

```
<smsc>-----<bearerbox>-----<SQLBOX>------<smsbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the rate that Kannel sends msgs per minute you can use the following:

```
cat /var/log/kannel/access.log|grep "send-SMS request added"|cut -d ":" -f 1,2|sort|uniq -c
```